# Kill processes older that one day by its name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a question much related to the problem.
Here's my code:

```
ps -eo pid,etime,cmd|grep ${1}|grep -v grep|awk '{if ($2>="23:59:59") print $1}'|xargs kill -9
```

I am trying to kill all processes with specific name which etime is more than a day. It worked well that way until i was told that the script cannot kill processes that represent date in a format like: 1-23:00:00.

Changing variable $2 in awk procedure to 1-00:00:00 kills all processes with given name. Can you give me a hint how to format etime properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of changing the awk script, I suggest changing `ps` option `etime` into `etimes`.

With `etimes` you got the lifetime **in seconds**. you are free to choose to kill or not kill if the value `> or <` a certain value. even, `$2>=somevalue1 && $2<= somevalue2`

Comment: Well, my Ubuntu box says it doesn't know anythin' about etimes:         ERROR: Unknown user-defined format specifier "etimes"

Comment: The [ChangeLog](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/NEWS?view=markup) suggests that it got implemented in 2011 with `procps-3.2.9` (so kinda "recently").

Comment: @alexeygaidamaka in this case, you could live with `etime`, and in your awk, check if there is a `-` in `$2` (`$2~/-/`). if matched, it means `x-xx:xx:xx` format. you could do kill or not kill.

Comment: @Adrian Frühwirth. As far as i can see, ubuntu 12.04 relies on  procps_3.2.8-11ubuntu6. Which builds from Debian repo. So, not so recently.

Comment: @alexeygaidamaka What I meant was that the addition might have been too recent enough to have hit Debian which would explain why you don't have it.